# Adding content to dashboard of liferay user other than admin

Tags: liferay, dashboard, liferay-7

I am new to using Liferay, and practicing currently on Liferay DXP. I have created various user, and wanted to add different content to dashboard of any user. Such as asset publisher which will list all the assets published by that user. I am able to add this modified content only for Admin User. I am not able to find any setting where I can change the look and feel of dashboard for every user.
Can anyone please help me where I can find it? It might be pretty simple but I am unable to find it. 
Thank you in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the ADT. Modify the templates as per requirement and on user roles. You won't be able to deliver content as per individual user but to roles. You can also have portlet preferences to show different content on different criteria. This all is possible. You will have to study the subject more. It will be very difficult to detail out the whole stuff here. But yes with ADT in Liferay 7 / DXP you have a lot of flexibility.